# Give access to more than one user

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I already have the `'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SUPERUSER', 'ROLE_USER'` roles set up and they are working perfectly. Now, **I need to give access to 3 particular users to a certain page** (with user names: admin1, admin2, admin3).

I tried the [controller-centric approach](http://spring.io/blog/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/), as follow...

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

@Secured(["authentication.name == 'admin1'", "authentication.name == 'admin2'", "authentication.name == 'admin3'"]) 
def transferMoney() {...}
```

But that only gave access to the first user, the `admin1`, the rest 2 didn't have the access.

Then I tried to give access from [static mapping](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/guide/requestMappings.html)...

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
   '/hostAdmin/account/transferMoney': ["authentication.name == 'admin1'", "authentication.name == 'admin2'", "authentication.name == 'admin3'"]
]
```

or

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
   [pattern: '/hostAdmin/account/transferMoney',  access: ["authentication.name == 'admin1'", "authentication.name == 'admin2'", "authentication.name == 'admin3'"]]
]
```

But both of them had no effect, the `/hostAdmin/account/transferMoney` page was open to ALL.

Can someone please help me? I really have to figure out how to give access to these 3 users only. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How about `http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#requestmapClass` ? You can even make it dynamic.

Comment: You are talking about the `Requestmap Class` [ https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/#requestmapClass ]​, right? I guess that might also work, but I was more interested in doing it using the `Configuring Request Mappings` [ https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/#requestMappings ] approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually pretty simple ^_^

I went with the controller-centric approach. And both of these solutions worked....

```
@Secured(["authentication.name == 'admin1' || authentication.name == 'admin2' || authentication.name == 'admin3'"])
```

or

```
@Secured(closure = {
   assert request
   assert ctx
   authentication.name == 'admin1' || authentication.name == 'admin2' || authentication.name == 'admin3'
})
```

Hope someone finds this helpful :)